# How do I help myself recover from death?

Tags: dnd-4e

What exactly can I do when I'm dying?

Is is possible for a priest to heal himself while dying with healing word?

D&D 4th ed seems very easy to learn, but a lot of things confuse me when I'm out there DM'ing.

Comment: Made your title represent your question. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 8):

Dying normally prohibits taking any actions whatsoever besides rolling a death saving throw at the end of each turn.

The [Dying](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=136) condition does this indirectly by inflicting the [Unconscious](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=146) condition which says:

> While a creature is unconscious, it is helpless, it can’t take actions,

As with most things, there are exceptions.

Comment: should probably note that a 20 on a death saving throw gives you a healing surge

Comment: Major exceptions: Bonuses to saving throws, bonuses to death saving throws, being a revenant. Note that achieving a 20+ (not rolling a 20) is necessary to gain the free surge, save via feat where it then becomes 18-20.

Comment: Also, a Warforged can elect to take 10 on a death saving throw, which can result in a free surge if the Warforged has the right combination of items and feats.